# ParseObject test failed with security exception

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am following the quick start guide and I am getting an error for

```
private void parseServerTest(){
   ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject"); 
  testObject.put("foo","bar");
   testObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() { 
    @Override
     public void done(ParseException e) {
       if(null != e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
       }else{
         Log.d(TAG,"no parse error.") 
      } 
    }
      });
 }
```

[Unless the instructions is missing something, I think I have done everything to the letter](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing)

**In case it matters, my app is in development, and does not exist on the playstore yet: not even as a draft**

Here is the error trace:

com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure
at com.parse.ParseRequest.newTemporaryException(ParseRequest.java:368)
at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:206)
at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:198)
at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:235)
at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:486)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:1259)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1197)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:392)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:295)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:208)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
at com.parse.ParseURLConnectionHttpClient.executeInternal(ParseURLConnectionHttpClient.java:42)
at com.parse.ParseHttpClient$ParseNetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(ParseHttpClient.java:155)
at com.parse.ParsePlugins$1.intercept(ParsePlugins.java:111)
at com.parse.ParseHttpClient$ParseNetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(ParseHttpClient.java:144)
at com.parse.ParseHttpClient.execute(ParseHttpClient.java:119)
at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:195)
at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:192)
at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:610)
at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:702)
at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:690)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:318)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:219)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:113)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:574)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:320)
... 29 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
... 35 more

Comment: I do not know much about Parse, but the error indicates that the SSL validation did not work for the HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a time delay. I moved on to something else. And now four hours later, I run the very sam code and it works. I changed nothing. So there must be some sort of time delay for newly opened parse accounts.